Can I create a JAR file in RAM and run with java runtime that calling C++?
Can I create a JAR file on RAM and run with java runtime? Java run time needs a JAR file, or class files saved on PC HDD. Can I save a JAR file, like a byte array object in RAM and run with the java runtime?

Pretty sure that the answer is no. But you could save to a RAM file system. What's your OS?

Windows 10 and Debian based Linux

No problem with Debian in /dev/shm. btw, to the editors: this is not the same as loading a class in RAM

@YALCIN Can you clarify if you want to create this JAR file externally and put it on the class-path/module-path at launch, or if you want to create this JAR file as part of your application and load the classes dynamically all at run-time?

@Slaw Normally, I save the jar file with C++ to a specific file path. Then I run the Java runtime via C++. I am looking for a way to run it as an object via RAM without any file path.

This is looking shady... (Ծ‸ Ծ)
